# how to create identify id for bulk upload csv file in sql server and cake php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

i want to create an id for my each bulk of upload file to identify and make sure each bulk of file are unique.
my column in RAS_Off_Upload table:

```
[RAS_Code]
[Value]
[Remark]
[SOF]
[Created_by]
[CLN_No]
[Lot_No]
[Prod]
[Date]
[Time]
[id]
[Line]
[Up_Time]
```

for example:
the upload process continue every 1 hour, so what i need is first batch uploaded file all row will have same id as 1, then the second batch upload file will have same id as 2.....then continue .... the id is increment...

i'm not sure whether to do it on cake php or add query on sql server. 
appreciate all the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach:

- Add a column to the RAS_Off_Upload table eg "BatchLoadID"
- At the end of the bulk upload process, run this:

(note: I'm assuming that it will be run every hour and finished well before the hour.)

```
DECLARE @LastBatchLoadID INT = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(BatchLoadID), 1) FROM RAS_Off_Upload);
SET @LastBatchLoadID = @LastBatchLoadID + 1;
UPDATE RAS_Off_Upload SET BatchLoadID = @LastBatchLoadID WHERE BatchLoadID IS NULL;
```

Comment: thank you for the comment! when i run it in sql server it will show Incorrect syntax near ')'.i'm not sure what is the problem. i'm sorry i'm new to sql server.

Comment: can you try again now? I had an extra bracket in the first statement.

Comment: It works successfully! Thank you very much for helping! i want ask is it i need to store in the stored procedure to save it to run frequently? or create a schedule job?

Comment: Yes you could wrap it in a SP. I'd have it run exactly after the end of the batch upload task.

Comment: thank you! i facing another problem, when i double upload the file, the query will not recognize the batch of the file. for example if 1 file contain 7 row of data then if i continous upload 9 file it will show 63 rows with BatchLoadID 1. i have 9 line doing the process, so that means every hour will have 9 file upload in database. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Only suggestion would be to run the SP after each individual file upload, not the batch of files.